# Corrupted Database Sql Server CE (Windows Mobile CE 5.0)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

**I have error when i try to deploying my project to smart device, so with the emulator every thing working fine , but when i use smart device , the database didn't work and when i open it , i get this error (i used visual studio 2008 and language C#) :**

```
Error : 0x800004005 E_FAIL
Native_Error: (25017)
Description : le fichier de base de données est peut-être endommagé. Exécuter l'utilitaire de réparation pour vérifier le fichier de la base de données [Database Name] .
Interface defining error: IID_IDBInitialize
Param:0: 0
Param:1: 0
Param:2: 0
Param:3: Program Files\ project_name\database_name.sdf
Param:4: 
Param:5:
```

Comment: Have you tried reparing the database?

Comment: Yes , i compact my database on the device and i manage and nothing changing .

Comment: Compact is not the same a repair ! And make sure to use the latest vesion of the SQLCE runtime...

Comment: how to repair my database so?

Comment: Call the Repair method on the SqlCeEngine class

Comment: Can you explain me how to do these?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.repair(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved , I reset my PDA and after that all works fine**